# How to provide flags to ruby script like -v , -o and place code accordingly?

Tags: ruby, command-line-arguments, flags

I have created one ruby script that I want to run with some flags on console say -v flag prints output on console and -o stores output in new file with file name I am taking from console using `gets()`

My code has following structure:

```
puts "Enter filename to analyze:\n\n"
filename = gets().chomp
puts "Provide filename to store result in new text file:\n\n"
output = gets().chomp
filesize = File.size(filename)
puts "File size in Bytes:\n#{filesize.to_i}\n"
pagecontent = filesize - 20
puts "\n\nData:\n#{pagecontent}\n\n"
File.open(filename,'r') do |file|
         #whole process with few do..end in between that I want to do in 2 different #ways.
    #If I provide -v flag on console result of this code should be displayed on console
    #and with -o flag it should be stored in file with filename provided on console #stored in output variable declared above
end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use stdlib [OptionParser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html)

Comment: I know this OptionParser but how can I put my code in its options so it works as I want?